# Does UglifyJS2 support base64-encoded in-source-maps?

Tags: javascript, node.js, uglifyjs2

I'm using [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) to compress an output file from Browserify. Browserify has generated its own source map which it tacks the bottom of the file like so:

```
//@ sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo...
```

I've got an error my JS somewhere in one of the files I've require'd, but Chrome is telling me the error occurred somewhere in the browserify output file rather than pointing me all the way back to require'd file.

The [`in-source-map` option](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#usage) doesn't say anything about base64-encodings, so I haven't set it to anything.

Answer (score -1):

i think sourcemap with uglified js has not support yet.

our team deploy minified source and debug it by Chalres's Map Local or Fiddler's autoresponder with not minified source with sourcemap.